# Google flight RPC JSON response

Tags: android, json, http-post, rpc, json-rpc

I am trying to get the JSON response from the Google Flight page.I looked into the following tutorial which explains how to get it [link](http://www.nohup.in/blog/using-json-google-flights).So I created an HttpPost request in Android and added all the required headers I got from the Google chrome to emulate a request(I was inspecting the request/response in my chrome browser).My question is how do I get the JSON response back.Heres my code so far.

```
public class SearchScreen extends Activity {
private static final String URL = "http://www.google.com/flights/rpc";
                                //"www.google.com/flights/#search;f=SJC;t=EWR,JFK,LGA;d=2012-04-05;r=2012-04-12"

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_screen);
    new AirplaneDetailsAsyncTask().execute(URL);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

private class AirplaneDetailsAsyncTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
        try {
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(streamToString(getAssets().open("json_payload.txt"))));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        post.addHeader("Host", "www.google.com");
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        post.addHeader("X-GWT-Permutation",
                "C8210E5F468630F84E578D8EDE10A1A0");
        post.addHeader("X-GWT-Module-Base",
                "http://www.google.com/flights/static/");
        post.addHeader("Referer", "http://www.google.com/flights/");
        post.addHeader(
                "Cookie",
                "PREF=ID=e2a92b3380d7d27f:U=3d554774092713bb:LD=en:TM=1358479701:LM=1380698072:DV=ItTa9H05UtgwsKnDG0OzXrRI8wzwgvK6-YzRssPfBQAAACoAp5J-Wg59AQAAAA:GM=1:S=UCXKy-x_emr9K3SO; HSID=AgVJtn-g2CDMiOMYl; SSID=A4yKK8G7fF8e5M01T; APISID=s-DKCLDgya0AD2eY/ArIOuAT3DXpIkznme; SAPISID=muzbz8j6Wy5YybG8/A3d1OIAjmhDsC_WXo; NID=67=wDEHoc3k9xdwS2WTBxz5Q0fzrmmwHphYHoKamTgFPUb17DwM-dFWJp4sJdEciRCn9RH7wdk1b97eF94zZS0IZ9SgTddQnLr5ht8Qsc2esrtU2LIlcIHyFVC9RRWs4h1f2rMCxGeWybkU_dgiqrqr2UQHkSSJSemCfxJV_FhF-gEG6b8KKjzWKzsBVtQS0gUG7g6rFZkDPDwZU-yD25Hh3-XoQkkTQoIG7k-y3pTG06-J-tUjRMNZbjBzoBN_ZYZRowSOCXJlkuSUku-SpEaDKd7IoUJ5Z3fBSzU; S=account-recovery=4KJarpZsJ5s:travel-flights=bFOuuLXsJoYhlhLnM7sMuQ; SID=DQAAAIQCAADA-EGq6XJtdkoCOaR9Dot7zk6oOuGFKSWS3t2aWMaB6rGfOleOuhydcutRWbQst5pTXflQuHHdqf8XlzHMxEdXTNDF4So282agqwLuI0b4TdEnOHKIxr1ToYtELmE5PaP-0tfDoF3NRFVSlnIfip0ty7AZGUX3oBv8ejSIn3Z-jn_Pd-Dg4Y4WOa70W9noFxkH0lok1-fk4TSUjZEhJRJPu4LydNCQFWjRJ6EMW22twsAHHTSqt92Nj4tFY9zzaJer7PIiYL7VU3SmGRwNRESR-vq-lEyDexnjoVgx5p0ck1lvGRI1CQ8RlAGSMoA0obU8fDspcQG4o2bugltVCb080aSjpi_JWyJhZOTI7dwYl8po7Z1ztf98PeS6uf2fFM1kaZ2DynIWfuDOWSh1TLsW24l3x4rIrEthH3NTd1f_lMyfyiRkMoiTKPaeqo-S1V-7_YzqJA8Us0L8q2ChW641nbEHTtURvoj0g8vNKrSfP0AgvxUb1Hmh2v2EzlHoTsAEkf8GYlCAP-VV6Z50IaNW93NUxSc-pD1TLSXL_tNqV0pG4IXJf1RD6dST2xojvZjEdznMXqTughtt1jdOp_2RaQSauOSCOUYE9v7MUmn4CxE1LfvFHW2Hq5zaErOjj5GmBSd-8n6M0BaBv2Kx7MdU3wwGgZJYVdwaTbnl1a6-BsXbUARSZIbQZ6plwUGjHGiWLvFoGY3l2YElBX9irN46Mts87A8kb2tSXuN6DOhRurdebChUkXYxcAt0OcoXIYTiTrQWr4QpPfrX1pt2imQqRTlj1E0t8nkg684tKbF6w2Fsul06Wlq1yIHFOdVffklF7BSSoFNS8oAAG-JfOYJu_-FuRQQbXlBazJUsa_DO-w");
        post.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        //post.addHeader("Content-Length","1255");
        post.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        String entityBody;
        try {
            response = client.execute(post);
            int respnseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            switch (respnseCode) {
            case 200:
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                if (entity != null) {
                    entityBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                    Log.d("Entity", entityBody);

                }
                break;

            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
    private String streamToString(InputStream inputStream ){
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return total.toString();
    }

}
```

}

The following is the response string I am receiving

Flights - Google Search

var **JS_ILT** = new Date();

#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important;}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important}
var **JS_INI** = "[,[,[,[14,1088,1115,1179,1171,1166,1178,1118,1117,1064,1143,1105,1185,1106,1133,1023,1109,1174,1060,1043,1163,1161,1154,1159,1202,1150,1160,1156,1172,15,10]],[,\42USD\42,\42$\42,\42\u00a4#,##0\42,\42\u00a4#,##0.00\42,\42#,##0\42],[,2,1609.344,\42#,##0\42,\42#,##0.0\42],\42google-travel\42,\42typeId:72275\42,\42ADS25WNrXN2r90yVrxoc2cGLL7byq1lyPXBcDPuISN0-8h2S_kUgpIUaPCwDlQoEipKwyJ7E7ooMJtl_HjfJJOv5EIoI8BrHKVaEvnBdZYk9ur5urOwqXwZoqiE3ZtMlhVA8dXL1Rd4Hia5rkMFBC6JVRnxLjW5avoIXio1_-S1mV7t4b20FEDBflib8wQ\42,\42.com\42,\42en\42,1,,,,,,\42https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue\u003d_CONTINUE_\42],[,\42LAX\42,\42Los Angeles\42,33.9425,-118.40806,[\42LAX\42,\42VNY\42,\42WHP\42,\42QLO\42,\42CCD\42,\42JWC\42],[\42LAX\42],\42United States\42,\42CA\42,\42US\42,\42California\42,\42///lh3.ggpht.com/SJl6YCFFaYdELEiAZhbxZkMpyc65BFrlJd6G-m803O0n5EVMFDZmYibv1ie8KQ\42],[[,\42LAX\42,\42Los Angeles International\42,\42Los Angeles\42,\42LAX\42,\42United States\42,33.9425,-118.40806,\42CA\42,\42US\42]],[[,\42ONEWORLD\42,\42Oneworld\42],[,\42SKYTEAM\42,\42SkyTeam\42],[,\42STAR_ALLIANCE\42,\42Star Alliance\42]],,[[,\42_web\42,\42Web\42],[,\42_fli\42,\42Flights\42],[,\42_mor\42,\42More\42],[,\42_few\42,\42Fewer\42],[,\42isch\42,\42Images\42],[,\42#map\42,\42Maps\42],[,\42shop\42,\42Shopping\42],[,\42vid\42,\42Videos\42],[,\42nws\42,\42News\42],[,\42bks\42,\42Books\42],[,\42blg\42,\42Blogs\42],[,\42dsc\42,\42Discussions\42],[,\42rcp\42,\42Recipes\42],[,\42app\42,\42Applications\42],[,\42pts\42,\42Patents\42]],1]";

(function(){var gs=document.createElement('script');var wmm=window.matchMedia;var hires=!!wmm && !wmm('(-webkit-device-pixel-ratio:1.0)').matches && !wmm('(-moz-device-pixel-ratio:1.0)').matches;gs.src=!hires?'static/3AB5E5242B57171E6FA8BDDC5CF6C944.cache.js':'static/CC76A5EF859E30018C45EE797352718D.cache.js';gs.type='text/javascript';gs.async=true;document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(gs);})();

(function() {  var script = document.createElement('script');  script.type = 'text/javascript';  script.src = 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/feedback/api.js';  document.body.appendChild(script);})();

Search Images Mail Drive Calendar Mobile More »Google Flight Search has not been optimized for your browser. For best results, please try Chrome, Firefox 3.5+, Internet Explorer 8+, Safari 4+.   Close

Update :After pointing the rpc end point server I get a responseCode 405 Method Not Allowed.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to make a post request against www.google.com/flights/rpc, instead of "https://www.google.com/flights/#search;f=SJC;t=EWR,JFK,LGA;d=2014-03-11;r=2014-03-15"? The response you're getting is strange, it should be a JSON not that script.

Comment: Update :After pointing to the rpc end point server I get a responseCode 405 Method Not Allowed.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210903/can-google-flights-data-be-queried-from-google-api

Comment: Yes that was the first link I checked before posting my code.Thanks!